# Manually start scheduled launchd job

Tags: mac-osx-server, launchd, launchctl

On our Mac OS X (10.6) Server we have setup several backup scripts that are controlled by `launchd` and launched at specific times. For this we have defined `StartCalendarInterval` and this all works very well.

Now it happens that I would like to start one of these jobs out of schedule, but this does not start the job (but also does not give an error/warning):

```
sudo launchctl start org.job-label
```

The manpage of launchtl states that `start` is intended to test on-demand jobs, no word of scheduled jobs. **Is there a way to kickstart scheduled jobs?**

---

Edit after getting the response: Yes, manually starting scheduled jobs also works via the `launchctl start` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, maybe this helps to debug your issue:

Set the log level to debug:

`sudo launchctl log level debug`

Tail the system.log:

`sudo tail -f /var/log/system.log &`

Try to start your job again:

`sudo launchctl start org.job-label`

Comment: Ha, thanks, that helped. I only saw that the job wasn't running but forgot that it had its own error log, and there I found that it terminated early due to a missing directory. Fixed that, now I can start it via `launchctl start org.job-label`. Thanks for the nudge!

Comment: `Unrecognized subcommand: log`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use `sudo launchctl start foo` to manually start a scheduled LaunchDaemon on macOS Ventura and it did not work.

However, I stumbled upon the `kickstart` subcommand of `launchctl` and it did work:

`sudo launchctl kickstart foo`

The description of the `kickstart` subcommand from the man page says:

> ```
>  kickstart [-kp] service-target
>          Instructs launchd to run the specified service immediately,
>          regardless of its configured launch conditions.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo launchctl -w load /Library/LaunchDaemons(Agents)/org.job-label
```

Comment: This would load the job, which it already is, but not start it.